# SQL Server 2012 creating tables and values

Tags: sql, sql-server

For some odd reason I can't create a table and because if that I can't insert any values into those tables. This is a new database and I am having a bit of a brain fart.. any help??? thanks

```
CREATE TABLE Customers 
(
    CustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    CustomerFName NVARCHAR(20),
    CustomerLName NVARCHAR(25),
    DateOfTravel DATETIME,
    TravelLocation NVARCHAR(25),
    AgencyID NVARCHAR(25) FOREIGN KEY (Agencies)
)
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: `AgencyID NVARCHAR(25) FOREIGN KEY (Agencies)` is invalid. Please read the manual: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 1):

Example of a working code

```
create table Agencies 
(
AgencyID nvarchar(20) primary key,
AgName nvarchar(40),
AgAddress nvarchar(40),
AgPhone int
)

CREATE TABLE Customers 
(
CustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
CustomerFName NVARCHAR(20),
CustomerLName NVARCHAR(25),
DateOfTravel DATETIME,
TravelLocation NVARCHAR(25),
AgencyID NVARCHAR(20) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Agencies(AgencyID)
)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: so id have to create agencies first?

Comment: @JackWindul: ***YES!!*** Things you want to *reference* **must exist** when you're establishing the reference ....

Comment: thank you, i honestly never knew of such a command(REFERENCES) was needed to complete the link. As i am still unable to create the next two tables i also need

Comment: You need to create the parent table before child.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
   CustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
   CustomerFName NVARCHAR(20),
   CustomerLName NVARCHAR(25),
   DateOfTravel DATETIME,
   TravelLocation NVARCHAR(25),
   AgencyID NVARCHAR(25) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Agencies(Your_Agencies_ID_COLUMN)
)
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback, but i tried that as well, is it because my agencies table is not executed yet? because either way they are both linked together. this is the new error i get....

Comment: Msg 1767, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
Foreign key 'FK__Customers__Agenc__108B795B' references invalid table 'Agencies'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "Agencies table is not executed yed" ? if you mean that it is not created then you should create it before creating "Customers" table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE Agencies (
    AgencyID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (Customers),
    Agency1Address NVARCHAR(40),
    Agency1City NVARCHAR(40),
    Agency1Region NVARCHAR(40),
    Agency2Address NVARCHAR(40),
    Agency2City NVARCHAR(40),
    Agency2Region NVARCHAR(40),
    EmployeeID INT FOREIGN KEY(Employees)
    )
thats the problem, i have keys everywhere

Comment: also you need to fix the foreign key here :FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES 
 Employees(Your_Employees_ID_Column). Also here you should create Employees table before Agencies.

Comment: Thank you for that Abdullah, but i have created the employees successfully now but still unable to create both the customers and employees table

Answer (score 0):

There two ways of creating foreign key constrain:

- creating a foreign key constraint within the table definition

  ```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataSource]
     (
         [SurveyInstanceID] BIGINT
        ,[ProtoQuestionID] INT
        ,[Pts] TINYINT
        ,[PtsOf] TINYINT
        , CONSTRAINT [PK_DataSource] PRIMARY KEY ([SurveyInstanceID], [ProtoQuestionID])
     );

     CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataSourceComments]
     (
         [SurveyInstanceID] BIGINT
        ,[ProtoQuestionID] INT
        ,[Comments] NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,CONSTRAINT [FK_DataSourceComments_DataSource_SurveyInstanceID_ProtoQuestionID] 
         FOREIGN KEY ([SurveyInstanceID], [ProtoQuestionID]) 
         REFERENCES  [dbo].[DataSource] ([SurveyInstanceID], [ProtoQuestionID])  
      );
  ```
- creating a foreign key constraint for existing table

  ```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataSource]
     (
         [SurveyInstanceID] BIGINT
        ,[ProtoQuestionID] INT
        ,[Pts] TINYINT
        ,[PtsOf] TINYINT
        ,CONSTRAINT [PK_DataSource] PRIMARY KEY ([SurveyInstanceID], [ProtoQuestionID] )
     );

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DataSourceComments]
    (
        [SurveyInstanceID] BIGINT
       ,[ProtoQuestionID] INT
       ,[Comments] NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );

   ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DataSourceComments]
   ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_DataSourceComments_DataSource_SurveyInstanceID_ProtoQuestionID]
   FOREIGN KEY ([SurveyInstanceID], [ProtoQuestionID]) 
   REFERENCES   [dbo].[DataSource] ([SurveyInstanceID], [ProtoQuestionID]);
  ```

Note, that in both cases I am specifying the `FK` constraint name. It's is a recommended to have some naming convention which to apply to all new `FK`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your foreign key is incorrect... maybe try this?

```
CREATE TABLE Customers (
CustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
CustomerFName NVARCHAR(20),
CustomerLName NVARCHAR(25),
DateOfTravel DATETIME,
TravelLocation NVARCHAR(25),
AgencyID NVARCHAR(25) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Agencies(AgencyID)
)
```

Supposing "AgencyID" is the ID in your Agencies Table.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
CREATE TABLE Agency
( 
AgencyID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
Name NVARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE Customers 
(
    CustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    CustomerFName NVARCHAR(20),
    CustomerLName NVARCHAR(25),
    DateOfTravel DATETIME,
    TravelLocation NVARCHAR(25),
    AgencyID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Agency(AgencyID)
)
```

First you have to create the parent table ie, Agency table. Then create the child (Customers) and refer the parent.